# DML error logging.. handling bad records in Spark Delta Table

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

Is there some option to capture error records/bad records in error table when we load data from staging to fact/Hub tables. I am looking for DML error logging Oracle in Spark Delta tables.
if there is any bad records/rejected table and it should be load in another table instead of throwing error. i need direct solution ... not looking for data validation for before loading the data in fact table.. Please refer the below notebook which is published in pubic.

https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2167814208768909/75203411582892/266969774599527/latest.html

Answer (score 0):

Use option badRecordsPath, and load bad_records to required location, as follows:

```py
df = spark.readStream.format("cloudfiles") \
  .option("cloudfiles.format","parquet") \
  .option("badRecordsPath","req_path") \
  .schema(schema).load("source_path")
```

and then create **in-place delta table** at bad_records location

Comment: `bad_records` us when it can't parse the data, but author is asking for data validation, like, value isn't null, etc.